# rename lambda function (php)

Tags: php, lambda, rename

I build a (so far) pretty nice templating mechanism for a cms. Now I also added a set of developer tools to the UI for a better UX during development. The only problem I'm left with is that I have to use `create_function` to add my templates, and therefore have `lambda_xyz` instead of meaningful template or function names.

**Question:** Is there a way/work around to give meaningful names to lambda functions in php?

Comment: why do you _have to_ use lambdas?

Comment: The template parts and locations have a hierarchy. I match it in a custom function and add it to a global array. When the viewport gets rendered, the template parts get added. The lambda function works in between and I have to create the function on the fly.

Comment: If you are trying to give meaningful names to lambdas...shouldn't they just be regular methods instead?

Comment: @Kevin As I mentioned: There's a template part hierarchy for each template part. And there's a list of contextual template-part positions. Regular functions would fill books for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reference might be able to point you in the right direction:
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

---

**Anonymous functions require PHP 5 >= 5.3.0**

```
$function_name = 'meaningful_name';

// PHP 5 >= 5.3.0
$$function_name = function(){echo "I am connected to a meaningful name";}; 

// PHP 4 >= 4.0.1, PHP 5
$$function_name = create_function('', 'echo "I am connected to a meaningful name";');

// Then you can call your function like this
$meaningful_name();
```

If this isn't what you are looking for, can you update your question with what you are trying to accomplish in more detail?

Comment: I already read through the php.net links to `create_function` and anonymous functions. Any hint more in detail?

Comment: @Gabi Purcaru This ends in "_syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE_".

Comment: @kaiser - Was missing a `;` at the end of the function, so  you might need to add that in

Comment: That works (haven't seen something like this before). Only the IDE yawns :)

Comment: @kaiser - I have added the PHP4/5 solution as well

Comment: It works in both cases, but ... here comes the _but_: (CMS handles it like this) The function is called from a global array by another function using `call_user_func_array()`. And there it will drop an error: "_call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'example' not found or invalid function name_". As it's part of the CMS, I can't get around it... annoying.

Comment: Wordpress. It's part of the Plugin API.

Comment: @kaiser let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1967/discussion-between-afuzzyllama-and-kaiser)